Google and Normal Authentication(Sign-In and Sign-up) Work on Desktop devises but Not on Mobile Devices in React
I'm working on a MERN stack project where the authentication system (both Google sign-in/sign-up and normal email/password authentication) works perfectly on desktop devices, but I’m encountering issues on mobile devices. When testing the application on mobile, the Google sign-in and sign-up, as well as the normal sign-in and sign-up functionalities, do not work as expected.
enter image description here
this is my UserAuthForm.jsx
Here's some more context

Frontend: React
Backend: Node.js/Express
DataBase: mongodb
Environment: Deployed with Vercel for frontend, MongoDB for the database

What I've tried

Cleared browser cache and cookies.
Checking different web browsers and different devices.(Google chrome, firefox, safari)
Mobile Browsers Tested: Chrome, Safari

enter image description here
Mobile Browsers comming error
Has anyone faced a similar issue with Google and normal authentication working only on desktop but not on mobile devices? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.
